# How does emu4ios Transfer cracked Apps with out jailbreak?

Tags: iphone, ios

Today I came across a strange kind of website that helped me save an app from Safari, to my iPhone 5 on iOS 7. The point being I didn't authenticate the App in the App Store, still it's there. Also fiddling a bit with the mechanism it used I was able to port an other cracked app to my iPhone. So my question being, How is it possible when my OS is not jail broken?

[image]

Comment: What signing profiles exist on your phone? If they were using an enterprise or developer deployment certificate then things would make sense that they could strip the code signing and replace it with other credentials that Apple engineered into the OS.

Comment: This is a new iPhone, I have never programmed on this till now.

Comment: If you see in the screenshot you can see I transferred an app that has not been cracked. I bought this with my brothers id and it is working on my iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this specific site and have no intention to do so, but it appears based on how-tos and screenshots that they are using some variation of the Enterprise Distribution Profile.  (Though I'm not sure how they avoid UDID registration.  It may have something to do with the notion of the requirement to roll your device's date back?)

Installing such an app looks like this, from [this article](http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2011/01/21/1/how-to-distribute-your-ios-apps-over-the-air) which explains how to use it to distribute beta apps:

[image: Enterprise Distribution Profile example]

Installing an app in this fashion, which I understand is a violation of Apple's developer policies if done to publicly distribute an application, does not require you to go through the App Store.  However, by doing so, you're explicitly circumventing Apple's vetting and, in my opinion, increasing your risk.  I recommend avoiding such downloads except in the context of internal enterprise software distribution or beta testing with a developer.

Comment: You can see that I added an app which my brother bought, from his Apple ID, My point being now that I can add just any apps to my iPhone with out actually buying them there?

Comment: Your provided link is not working.

Comment: Link works for me, and I just double-checked it.  I have no answer for your other question.

Answer (score 3):

When it asks you to change your date before 2012. reason why is before 2012 there was a update that validates cracked apps to be downloaded. When you set it before its sort of removing some of the validates. When it first downloads it downloads a provisioning profile which allows the cracked app to download due to the profile permissions.